# How to use on model into another model

Tags: javascript, mongodb, loopbackjs

I have two separated models name employee and user with some common data and a accountId to link each other. One record for each model is as below:

```
Employee
 _id:1639137618164 
 name:"*****"         
 sites:Array
 company:”Software”
 jobTitle: “Associate Software Engineer”
 email:"*****"
 phonesms:"1"
 phonevoice:"1"
 licenseNumber:""
 avatarStamp:0
 pined:false
 accountId: 1639129314021 //link attribute
 countryCodeSms:"US"
 countryCodeVoice:"US"
 inviteCode:"09611"
 emergencyRoles: Object
 invite: "booksRbUoSM"
```

and for User is

```
_id:1639129314021 
firstName:"*** ***" 
lastName:"****"
companyName:"SITS"
passwordReset:""
activated:true
accountId:1639129314021 // link attribute
siteId:-1     
role:0     
last:1639137913873
blocked:false
blockedtext:""
trialend:1640338913781
paytype:1
hashAccess:Array
emergencyEnabled:false
visitorTypes:Array
sitesLimit:2
manualCreation:false
username:"*************"     
password:"**********************************"     
email:"*********************"
passwordNotification:true
passwordLifecycle:1646906375986
isNewUser:true
listFeature:Object
```

I want to search from user model whether if any employee exists with that accountId or not, if there is employee associated with accountId, then add new employee with the available common data. otherwise not. How can i do this in loopback. I am stuck here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Loopback 4

### Solution 1:

In your user controller where you have the access to the UserRepository

**Assuming you know the accountId and the accountId only exists if you have an employee record you can have a method**

```
@get('/users/{accountId})
async findUserWhoIsAnEmployee(@param.path.string('accountId') accountId: string){
 return this.userRepository.findOne({where: {accountId}})
}
```

**Assuming you don't know the accountId...**

You can access the employee repository in your UserController by passing it as an argument in the constructor function and finding the user, then checking in the Employee record. *(Not optimal since two queries will be made on your DB)*

```
export class UserController{
  constructor(
     @repository(UserRepository) public userRepository: UserRepository,
     @repository(EmployeeRepository) private employeeRepository: EmployeeRepository
  )
  // returns employee record or null if none
  @get('/users/{id}/employee-record)
  async findUserWhoIsAnEmployee(@param.path.string('id') id: string){
   const user = await this.userRepository.findById(id);
   return (!user) ? null : this.employeeRepository.findOne({where: {accountId: user.accountId}})
  }
}
```

### Solution 2:

**Where you have a relation between the User and Employee Model (*hasOne, preferrably*)**

You can find that employee record on the user

```
// returns employee record of a user if exists 
@get('/users/{id})
async findUserWhoIsAnEmployee(@param.path.string('id') id: string){
 return this.userRepository.findById(id).employeeRecord()
}
//Where employeeRecord is a reference property on the user Model.
```

Comment: this is for loopback version 4 ... but i needed for version 2 .. anyway still deserve this !

Answer (score 2):

I am using loopback version 2.x.x. It turns out to be very simple

```
currentModel.app.models.modelYouWantToAccess
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with below

```
var  employee_data = Employee  .filter(x => User.map(y => y.accountId).includes(x.accountId));
```

Comment: i think the easier way is to search in the employee collection with that accountId you have on your user object.

Comment: That is not the way ... where did the Employee came from ? They are separate models of loopback

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are using mongoose and you have this part in your `User` model:

```
accountId: {
  type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
  ref: 'Employee',
  required: [true, 'this field must be provided']
},
```

You can add a `populate` method to your schema so that related model's data gets added to each time you request data with `User.find(), findOne,` and all other methods starting with 'find'

```
userSchema.pre(/^find/, function(next) {
  this.populate({
    path: 'accountId',
    options: { // you can populate only some fields if you want
      select: 'name company jobTitle'
    }
  })

  next()
})
```

Then, you can use your `User` model as always, but now related `Employee` data gets added:

```
const given_id = "65465458qw7d7q1q7w1x" 
const user = await User.findOne({accountId: given_id})

// Note: you can use User.find if there can be
// more than one user with that accountId.
```